# What is wrong with this Haskell let-in indentation?

Tags: haskell, syntax, indentation, let, do-notation

In the below Haskell code, I get an error "parse error on input 'in'". From what I've read, the indentation I've used should be fine. I in fact use 'let' and 'in' with similar indentation ('let' aligned with 'in') successfully elsewhere in my code. What rule have I broken that causes this 'in' to be a problem? If I add a space in front of 'in' (making it 1-space furthur in than 'let') it compiles fine.

```
runTests :: IO ()
runTests = do
             let results = fmap testLispExpr testLispText
                 resultStrings = fmap show results
                 putSeq (x:xs) = do putStrLn x
                                    putSeq xs
                 putSeq [] = return ()
             in putSeq resultStrings
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, this is equivalent to `runTests = mapM_ (print . testLispExpr) testLispText`

Answer (score 7):

`let` syntax in `do` blocks is a little funny. If you want to use `in`, you have to indent it to the right of the `let`. Alternatively, you can omit the `in` altogether, and the `let` bindings will be visible for the rest of the `do` block:

```
           do
             let ....
                 ....
             putSeq resultStrings
         --  ..... (more `do` statements)
         --  ^^ must all start on the same column
```

#### Edit

As Ørjan Johansen notes, the `do` isn't actually necessary at all in this case, since there's only one statement after `let`. So the other option is to omit the `do` while keeping the `in` keyword. And they also note that you can also write it as

```
runTests = mapM (print . testListExpr) testLispText
```

and really make things clean.

Comment: A third option is to skip the `do`, since there's only one statement.

Comment: started small (skip/omit), ended up with a pretty verbose edit... sorry for that. :)